# Easiest way to exit from menu

Tags: python

I finished all my homework but i forgot to put a cancel option under submenu. I do not want to change all my files, it took 2 days to do this. What will the easiest way to add a cancel and return to main menu option on sub_menu.py

**this is the sub_menu.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

## sub_menu.py

#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def how_many():
    while True:
        print
        print "  How many do you want to draw? -----Range is from 1 to 5-----"
        shape_num = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ')
        try: 
            shape_num = int(shape_num)
            if (1 <= shape_num <= 5):
                print "  Number ", shape_num ," is OK."
                break
            else:
                print
                print "  The number you entered must be from 1 to 5 only."
        except:
            print
            print "  Only numbers allowed - Please try again"
    return shape_num



#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def main():
    how_many()
#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#
```

---

**this is the main one**

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python

## my_menu.py

import sub_menu as s_m
import draw_shape as d_s

#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def main():
    while True:
        print
        print "  Draw a Shape"
        print "  ============"
        print
        print "  1 - Draw a triangle"
        print "  2 - Draw a square"
        print "  3 - Draw a rectangle"
        print "  4 - Draw a pentagon"
        print "  5 - Draw a hexagon"
        print "  6 - Draw an octagon"
        print "  7 - Draw a circle"
        print
        print "  X - Exit"
        print

        choice = raw_input('  Enter your choice: ')

        if (choice == 'x') or (choice == 'X'):
            break

        elif (choice >= "1" and choice <= "7"):
            my_shape_num = s_m.how_many()
            # draw in the middle of screen if == 1
            if (my_shape_num == 1):
                d_s.start_point(0, 0)
            else:
                d_s.start_point()
            #
            if choice == '1': 
                d_s.draw_triangle(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '2': 
                d_s.draw_square(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '3':             
                d_s.draw_rectangle(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '4':             
                d_s.draw_pentagon(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '5':             
                d_s.draw_hexagon(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '6':             
                d_s.draw_octagon(my_shape_num) 
            elif choice == '7': 
                d_s.draw_circle(my_shape_num)

            d_s.t.end_fill() # shape fill color --draw_shape.py-- def start_point

        else:
            print
            print '  Try again'
            print


#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#
```

---

**this is the drawshape one**

---

```
#!/usr/bin/python

## draw_shape.py

import turtle as t

#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def start_point(x=-240, y=0):
    # Added 23 dec 11 baris
    t.color("black", "red")
    t.shapesize(outline=8)
    t.begin_fill()
    #
    t.penup() 
    t.setpos(x, y) 
    t.pendown()

def spaces_after(x=120):
    t.penup() 
    t.forward(x)
    t.pendown()

#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def draw_triangle(num=1):
    for a in range(num): 
        for a in range(3): 
            t.forward(80) 
            t.left(120)
        spaces_after()
#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def draw_square(num=1):
    for a in range(num): 
        for a in range(4): 
            t.forward(80) 
            t.left(90)
        spaces_after()
#=========#=========#=========#=========#        
def draw_rectangle(num=1):
    for a in range(num):
        for a in range(2): 
            t.forward(80) 
            t.left(90)
            t.forward(40)
            t.left(90)
        spaces_after()
#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def draw_pentagon(num=1):
    for a in range(num): 
        for a in range(5): 
            t.forward(50) 
            t.left(72)
        spaces_after()
#=========#=========#=========#=========#        
def draw_hexagon(num=1):
    for a in range(num): 
        for a in range(6): 
            t.forward(50) 
            t.left(60)
        spaces_after()
#=========#=========#=========#=========#        
def draw_octagon(num=1):
    for a in range(num): 
        for a in range(8): 
            t.forward(40) 
            t.left(45)
        spaces_after()
#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def draw_circle(num=1):
    for a in range(num): 
        t . circle(50)
        spaces_after()
#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#
def main():
    start_point()

    draw_triangle()
    draw_square()
    draw_rectangle()
    draw_pentagon()
    draw_hexagon()
    draw_octagon()
    draw_circle()

    t.end_fill()

#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#=========#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in 2 lines of codes. 
in `sub_menu.py` you should add "0" handling like so

```
...
try:
            shape_num = int(shape_num)
            if ( shape_num == 0):
                return None
            if (1 <= shape_num <= 5):
                print "  Number ", shape_num ," is OK."
                break
            else:
                print
                print "  The number you entered must be from 1 to 5 only."
        except:
 ....
```

and in main.py you should do

```
my_shape_num = s_m.how_many()
            if ( my_shape_num is None):
                continue
```

This should reprint the main menu.

You should also add an instruction (press 0 to cancel) if you want.

Comment: thanks lot. it works perfect. How did i not think of this before??? How does all my code look?

Comment: your code looks great. I didn't have any problems finding my way around. keep at it